# Future Psychic gladiator. Criminals bribe him to throw match. Wins it by. projecting Roman soldier with short sword, defeating projected monster

Tags: story-identification, psychic

I read this in the 80s I think in a book from a UK library. It is a short story. In this world a small number of people are born with lumps on their heads and psychic powers.

Many of these people work as gladiators. They project 3D images the audience can see. These images fight with those projected by their opponent.

The protagonist is an aging gladiator past his prime.

His manager is offered a large bribe by an organised crime organisation for him to deliberately lose a match. Obviously they are betting huge sums on his opponent winning.

The manager takes the money but does not tell his client to throw the match. He thinks the protagonist will almost certainly lose in any case as his talent is not what it used to be.

In the fight, each gladiator conjures up projections of deadly creatures to fight with. They can only project one at a time. The protagonist is confused when his opponent telepathically tells him now is the best time to lose.

He is exhausted by this point of the contest and can project very little. He produces a Roman soldier who he has used many time; he knows every inch of him from memory. The gladiator knows his Roman soldier believes that there is no creature that cannot be killed by stabbing a sharp gladius into its belly. He does this and defeats the huge monster the other gladiator created.

Of course the criminals are very unhappy. They have lost lots of money betting on the loser.

A  group of thugs are sent to punish him for not throwing the math.

> They cut off the lump protruding from his head that gave him psychic powers. I think with a shovel. The final words are something like..(name) joined the ranks of ordinary men.

Comment: I read this story in the 1970s, in an issue of the Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction that I borrowed from my language arts teacher.

Comment: Thanks so we know it was written in the 70s or earlier and published in a  magazine 

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This story is "Dream Fighter", by Bob Shaw, which appeared in the February 1977 issue of "The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction". Your memories of the tale are good. The psychic gladiators fight in an arena where they sit on short pedestals - rolling off your pedestal is a signal of surrender. The protagonist's opponent fights with a towering, hairy, razor-clawed demon. The character probes the demon with his powers, and finds the manifestation to be 'hard', indicating that his opponent has put all of his energy into it, and intends to maintain it throughout the contest. One of the protagonist's early manifestations is a slope-shouldered dinosaur, which impresses the spectators with its size, but fails in combat with the demon. (The protagonist feels the pain of the damage that his manifestation receives) In the final round, he summons a familiar avatar: the roman centurion. This manifestation is smaller than he had hoped, due to his fatigue, but wins the contest, killing the demon-manifestation, and giving his opponent a first experience of arena-pain.
After that, the criminals excise his psychic organ (called a walnut in the story) with a shovel.

[image]